# Do we need Killing vectors to have wave vectors in a plane wave solution?

Tags: general-relativity, vector-fields, qft-in-curved-spacetime, plane-wave

It is well known, and there are other questions in this website that answer this, that one needs a stationary Killing vector field to judge if a plane wave has positive or negative frequency. If our plane wave is $f_i$ then it has a positive frequency if
$$\mathscr{L}_K f_i = i \omega f_i$$
and negative frequency if
$$\mathscr{L}_K f_i = - i \omega f_i,$$
where $K$ is the stationary Killing vector field. Then my question is the following: if we need a global timelike Killing vector field for frequencies, then do we also need global spacelike Killing vector fields to have a well defined notion of momentum of the wave?

Say we had a global spacelike Killing vector field $\xi$ and the same basis function $f_i$. Do we say that we have positive or negative (or a well defined momentum) of the plane wave, in any direction whatsoever, if
$$\mathscr{L}_\xi f_i = i k f_i$$